# I'm trying to auto populate labels(with parameters from object) on selecting option from dropdown list

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, .net-5

I'm new to mvc and html/js both.

So the basic idea of what I am trying to do is:

- Dropdown(used to select bookTitle)
- Labels below get auto populated with selected book details from dropdown(id,title,author,price,quantity,etc)
- Button on the side of these labels which will add this obj into a List
- Whole list will then be used for checkout

I'm stuck with the auto-populated labels and add button
Would be a grateful if anyone would be willing to help me

Here is my code:

'''

```
    @model IEnumerable<BookWebApp.Models.Books>
    @{
    ViewData["Title"] = "OrderBooks";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
    <html>
        <center>
          <h1>OrderBooks</h1>
          <hr/>

        <div id="Title">
            <select id="Title_Select">
             <option value="" selected-disabled>
             Book Names
             </option>

        @foreach(var item in Model)
        {
             <option value=@item.Title>
             @item.Title
             </option>
        
         }
            </select>
        </div>

        <button onclick="getValue()"> Check Details</button>
        <hr/>
        <div>
        <table class="table">
        <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th>
                       @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BookID)
                  </th>
                  <th>
                       @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
                  </th>
                  <th>
                       @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Author)
                  </th>
                  <th>
                       @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
                  </th>
                  <th>
                       @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Quantity)
                  </th>
                  <th></th>
             </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
              <tr>
                   //labels for obj here
              </tr>
         </tbody>
     </table>
     </div>

     </center>
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

To populate the list you can do as you did with the DropdownList with a foreach and insert all the fields in the order of the header and on the last one check with value id.
Finally, a push button for the with an onclick function.
In the onclick function you scroll through the list and take Id of all the checkboxes that have the checked property.
You now have the list of all the selected books.
if you want I can give you an example but I suggest you see for yourself that it is much more instructive, tell me if you want the example

Comment: I know how to populate the list
But I don't want it for all the items in the list
Only for the value that the user selected.. How would you do that?

Comment: one thing like that:$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ddl").change(function() {
        var strSelected = "";
        $("#ddl option:selected").each(function() {
            strSelected += $(this)[0].value;
        });
        var url = "/Home/MyAction/" + strSelected;

        $.post(url, function(data) {
            // do something if necessary
        });
    });
});

Comment: None of this makes sense to me as I don't know js :(
Can't it be done without js? With the help of C# maybe?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can add the labels to the list and then bring the list to the Checkout page, use `ajax` to post data or use MVC submission. I would recommend the first one (using `ajax`) because the page will not be refreshed.

Solution 1: Use ajax

1. Create a Controller method to save the record
2. Whenever the user click on the button, make an ajax call to post the item to the method, save it to somewhere (Persistence database or cache)
3. When user navigate to the check-out page, retrieve the list and display to the user
4. Also you may want to add a remove button for easily manage.

Here's the code to populate the labels:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
       <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BookID)
       </th>
       <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
       </th>
       <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Author)
       </th>
       <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
       </th>
       <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Quantity)
       </th>
       <th>
        <!-- This one is for the add button -->
       </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach(var label in Model.Labels)
    {
        <tr class="table-row">
            // labels for obj here
            <td class="label-id">@label.Id</td>
            <td class="label-id">@label.Title</td>
            <td class="label-id">@label.Author</td>
            <td class="label-id">@label.Price</td>
            <td class="label-id">@label.Quantity</td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn-add-to-collection" onclick="addLabel(this)"></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>

<script>
    function addLabel(el) {
        // query for the properties value then use ajax to post the data to controller
        // also save it to the current page state for easily modify
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi,
Thankyou for the suggestion.. I was wondering if you had any references for me to use ajax? As I have no experience with js

Also I still don't understand how will the labels populate only for the dropdown option selected.

Comment: You can start with this plain js here: [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp)
Or if you want to be faster I suggested you check on [jQuery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp)

Nowadays devs don't prefer jQuery because it's quite old and heavy. But it's good for beginners in my opinion.

Comment: Alright I'll look into it.
But how would the labels populate for only the item the user has selected?

Comment: @Wolvie_9016 In the foreach loop, check for the condition, then render the row
Something like this
`@foreach(var label in labels)
{
   if(label.IsSelected)
   {
       <tr>...</tr>
    }
}
`

Comment: I am not talking about the label.. I'm asking for the dropdown option selected in
             <option value=@item.Title>
                           @item.Title
             </option>

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple methods to achieve your goal to auto populate label data:

1. Set Attribute values to your select which comprise of details of books.
   1.1. Implement an onChange function for your select which will populate data from Select attribute in your labels.
2. Implement an onChange function for your select which will send an ajax call to your controller.
   2.1. Retrieve values from controller and populate relevant values in labels
3. Create a separate button, on its onClick send an ajax call to your controller.
   3.1. Retrieve values from controller and populate relevant values in labels

Now coming to Adding data in list:
Why providing separate buttons for all labels?
Why not add a button Proceed to check out?

And for that you can do:

```
$.each($(table).find('tbody tr'), function (j, row) {
});
```

in this code you get all your label values and push them in the list proceed as you please

I hope this helped, if you need code snippets for above mentioned processes, let me know, I will update my answer accordingly.

Edit 1, Solution 1

```
<div>
    <center>
        <h1>OrderBooks</h1>
        <hr />

        <div id="Title">
            <select id="Title_Select" onchange="SelectOnChange()">
                <option value="" selected-disabled>
                    Book Names
                </option>

                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <option value=@item.BookID>
                        @item.Title
                    </option>

                }
            </select>
        </div>

        <hr />
        <div>
            <table class="table" id="BooksTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BookID)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Author)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Quantity)
                        </th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <hr />
            <button onclick="ProceedCheckOut()"> Proceed to CheckOut</button>

        </div>

    </center>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {

        SelectOnChange = function () {
            var BookId = $("#Title_Select :selected").val();

            var URL = '/Underwriting/Case/GetBookDetailsById';
            var _data = {
                BookId: BookId
            };

            $.ajax({
                url: URL,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "html",
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify(_data),
                async: true,
                success: function (result) {
                    var Books = JSON.parse(result);
                    var tr = '<tr>' +
                        '<td id="BookID">' + Books.BookID + '</td>' +
                        '<td id="Title">' + Books.Title + '</td>' +
                        '<td id="Author">' + Books.Author + '</td>' +
                        '<td id="Price">' + Books.Price + '</td>' +
                        '<td id="Quantity">' + Books.Quantity + '</td>' + 
                        '</tr>';
                    $('#BooksTable > tbody').append(tr);

                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                    $Extention.HideLoader();
                    _$.Notification("YOU MIGHT BE ENTERING WRONG VALUES.", 200);
                }
            });
        }

        ProceedCheckOut = function () {
            var Books = new Object()
            $('#BooksTable tbody tr').each(function (i, field) {

                Books.BookID = parseInt($(field).find('#BookID').text());
                Books.Title = $(field).find('#Title').text();
                Books.Author = $(field).find('#Author').text();
                Books.Price = parseFloat($(field).find('#Price').text());
                Books.Quantity = parseInt($(field).find('#Quantity').text());
            });

            console.log(Books);
        }

    });
```

I have made minor changes to your code:

1. Implemented an onChange button, removed GetDetails button, In OnChange button i have called my controller function to get details from database against BookId.
2. Once i get book details from controller i render that data in my Ajax success
3. Created a Proceed to checkout button, this button gets data from table and inserts it in an object, now you can use that object to send book data to another page or your controller.

In case of further help please let me know

Comment: It would be wonderful if you could provide some code snippets. Also it would be really helpful if you had any video links? I am new to this so not much of it is making sense to me rn

Comment: Please check the edit to my answer, if you want any explanations or further help, please let me know